# Chebyshev's inequality problem with a coin

Tags: probability

I got this problem:

Suppose, to decide if a coin is balanced, we throw it 1000 times, and we reject the coin as balanced if the number of faces or the number of tails obtained is greater than or equal to 600. Use Chebyshev's inequality to determine the maximum percentage of balanced coins that are rejected with this procedure.

I just don't know how to express that you reject a coin if the number of tails or faces obtained is greater than or equal to 600.

Comment: A strange question as the null hypothesis is clearly a binomial distribution with parameters $n=1000$ and $p=\frac12$.  This will allow you to find the mean and variance and then use Chebyshev's inequality, though a direct use of the binomial distribution or of a normal approximation (with continuity correction) will give a better view of the probability of rejection when the null hypothesis is true

Comment: I agree, so I computed that the mean is 500 and the variance is 250, so that means that $P(|X-500| \geq 600) \leq 250/600^2 = 0.00006944$ Is that right?

Comment: No: You are interested in $P(|X-500| \geq 100)$